# Swift Framework in Xamarin iOS - NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [<UIViewController 0x7faff37075f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]

Tags: ios, swift, visual-studio, xamarin, frameworks

In have to show a `UIViewController` in *Xamarin.iOS* app from *swift .framework*

**In Swift file**

```
import UIKit

@objc(ConnectViewController)
open class ConnectViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var screenTitle: UILabel!

    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        screenTitle.text = "Connect.framework"
        screenTitle.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        screenTitle.layer.masksToBounds = true

    }
}
```

In *Storyboard* I have changed storyboard name and storyboard id for *ViewController*

[image]

**In community Xamarin iOS Binding Library - ApiDifinition.cs**

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace CustomLibrary
{
    [BaseType(typeof(UIViewController))]
    interface ConnectViewController
    {

    }
}
```

**In iOS App - ViewController.cs**

```
   NSBundle bundle = NSBundle.FromClass(new Class(typeof(ConnectViewController)));
            UIStoryboard storyBoard = UIStoryboard.FromName("CustomLib", bundle);

           PresentViewController(storyBoard.InstantiateViewController("Connecter"), true, null);
```

When I run a project. Its crashed after launch screen.

[image]